# ¿Cómo sumar un array con strings y números?

Tags: python, lista

Teniendo en una lista mezclados tanto números en tipo de variable String como números en tipo de variable enteros ¿Cómo puedo sumar todos los elementos?

Ejemplo:

```
lista=[7,6,'5',2,'1']
def sum_mix(arr):
    
    for e in (arr):
        if e == str:
            int(e)
    return sum(arr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que preguntar si el valor es un string, y en tal caso convertirlo antes de sumarlo.

Para preguntar si es un string, usas `type(valor) is str`.

Suponiendo que son todos enteros, usas `int()` para hacer la conversión. Si no, puedes usar `float()`.

```
def suma(numeros):
    total = 0
    for valor in numeros:
        if type(valor) is str:
            total += int(valor)
        else:
            total += valor
    return total
            
lista=[1,2,3,"4","5",10,"15"]
print(suma(lista))
```

produce:

```
40
```

**Análisis**

Siguiendo la recomendación de @abulafia, podemos reducir el código a simplemente:

```
def suma(numeros):
    total = 0
    for valor in numeros:
        total += int(valor)

    return total
```

que esta a un paso de las otras soluciones propuestas. Es la misma idea, expresada en pasos elementales.

La ventaja esencial de esta solución elemental frente a una solución concisa es su adaptibilidad. La vida no es perfecta, y puede que la lista traiga cosas que no se pueden convertir. Puede que mañana haya que convertir strings que contengan hexadecimales:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, "4", "5", "4.x", 10, "15", "0x10"]
```

Frente a tal demanda, simplemente amplio el código:

```
def suma(numeros):
    total = 0
    for valor in numeros:
        try:
            total += int(valor)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                total += int(valor, 16)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    return total
```

No he tenido que tocar el resto del programa, que corre sin cambios:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, "4", "5", "4.x", 10, "15", "0x10"]
print(suma(lista))

56
```

La otra ventaja es que puedo agregar chequeos automatizados. La idea es que tras cada cambio a la función, se ejecutan revisiones automáticas. Asi se puede detectar cualquier error introducido por el cambio en forma fácil y rápida.

Comment: No necesitas mirar si es de tipo string. Puedes aplicar `int()` a todos los elementos, pues si ya era `int` no va a cambiar. Por tanto la solución puede ser tan simple como: `print(sum(map(int, lista)))`

Comment: @abulafia. Después de mucho analizarlo, concluyo que tu solución es la número 1. Tan increiblemente concisa. La de RicardoA sería la número 2. Absolutamente pitonesca, bella, pero más complicada de leer.

Answer (score 3):

Puede aplicarse una combinación de una característica de python llamada "list comprehensions" y "ternary operator"

a través de "ternary operator" se determina si el elemento es de tipo int o no, en cuyo caso se intenta hacer la conversión.

```
lista=[7,6,'5',2,'1']
suma = sum([int(x) if not isinstance(x, int) else x for x in lista])
```

también puedes usar la función map, y una función lambda para incluir la condición de convertir sólo si no es int

```
sum(map(lambda x: int(x) if not isinstance(x, int) else x, lista))
```

esta última tiene la ventaja de que no se crea una nueva colección para aplicar la suma, en su lugar se aprovecha el iterador producido por map, útil si tuvieras un conjunto muy muy grande de datos pero en esos casos dependiendo del contexto de tu proyecto quizá sea conveniente usar numpy o pandas.

También map es muy útil si los datos no están en una lista, si no que se obtienen a través de un generador, imagina por ejemplo que sumas medidas arrojadas por algún dispositivo de hardware.

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta, pero recuerda que las que son solo código, son marcadas automáticamente por el sistema como "baja calidad" y entran en la cola de revisión de pares. Saludos

Comment: @PatricioMoracho. No requiere explicación. Es perfecto,

Comment: El negativo es mio.. y lo quitare apenas expliques tu respuesta segun como se ve en [answer] ;)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `sum` con `map`:

```
>>> elems=[1,2,3,"4","5",10,"15"]
>>> elems=[7,6,'5',2,'1']
>>> sum(map(int, elems))
21
>>> elems=[1,2,3,"4","5",10,"15"]
>>> sum(map(int, elems))
40
```